# How to hide elements in awesomium by id VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, awesomium

How to hide elements in awesomium by id in VB.NET? Is it something like this?

```
       Private Sub WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete(sender As Object, e As Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs) Handles WebControl.LoadingFrameComplete
    Dim hide = WebControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("header")
    If hide IsNot Nothing Then
        //i don't know what goes here

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [awesomium documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net)

Comment: I checked it, but i'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com) on your site to hide elements.

```
WebControl.ExecuteJavascript("$('#elementId').hide();");
```

I suppose you show html that you control, so you can easily add the jQuery scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

As somebody mentioned here and as you are correctly trying to do `WebControl.ExecuteJavaScript("js string")` is used for cases like this.

1) You could simply use something like `"document.getElementById('elementid').style.display = 'none'"` if you preffer classic javascript.

2) Or you could use Jquery as others mentioning and that would look like `"$('#elementid').hide();"` if there is already jquery included in page.

3) If there is no jquery included you would have to inject it by another javascript (more info at http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/02/how-to-easily-inject-jquery-into-any-web-page/ for example)

In all ways there is no need to return anything if you are not insisting on check if your script was succesfull i suppose.